# Zero questions on the site: Is it just me?

Tags: bug, questions

On more than one occasion visiting the main site, I've been told there are no questions. This is what it looks like, complete with the obligatory freehand circles:

[image: Screenshot of zero questions]

I don't know how that page is generated: this result means it **looks** like it's generated by my browser submitting a request to populate the results (using AJAX) which is coming back empty. That could mean a fault in any number of places in the chain connecting my browser to the SE database. However, examining requests using Chrome's developer tools or Firebug in Firefox doesn't support that methodology. It appears it's generated server-side and served as a static page.

If that is the case, then the server-side query — made by the SE engine on its database — is returning no questions.

What gives?

Comment: I've never seen this happen. I usually use Chrome.

Comment: What do you do to resolve it? Just refresh?

Comment: Yes: just refresh. But that doesn't help identify where the problem lies. (And no, it's not a case of PICNIC — "Problem in chair not in computer"!)

Comment: Maybe it was related to [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/295285/brief-outage-planned-for-wed-may-3-2017-at-8pm-us-eastern-0000-utc-like-a?cb=1). It happened to me one time yesterday and hasn't recurred since.

Comment: @Andrew A refresh fixing it puts it more in the server side than client, typically. Also, with how I understand the stack engine to work, it looks server side already.

Comment: @bruisedreed It might have been related. But since that was/will be midnight my time, and I wasn't/won't be at the computer, it's unlikely, I think. (I'm not sure which date the 0000UTC actually refers to).